# Div height becomes smaller with position:relative than absolute

Tags: html, css, less

Hi Stackoverflow users...

I have this website I'm trying to style really cool.

http://kebax.dk/blog

**As you see my problem is that the last part of the "border" does not cover the last two div's.**

Here's the structure of the Div's:

```
<div id="blog">
    <div id="bloghead">
        #Blog headline
    </div>
    <div id="blogbody">
        <p>Test tekst!!</p>
        <p>Test tekst!!</p>
        <p>Test tekst!!</p>
        <p>Test tekst!!</p>
        <p>Test tekst!!</p>
        <p>Test tekst!!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="blogcreditsleft">
        Written by: Kristian
    </div>
    <div id="blogcreditsright"><?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?></div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS behind it (you can also just check out my stylesheet too):

```
    #blog {
        .rounded();
        left:65px;
        position:relative;
        width:520px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding:5px;
        background:#052507;
    }

    #bloghead {
        color:#000000;
        background:#2BAC2B;
        padding:5px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #052507;
        font-size:14pt;
    }
    #blogbody {
        color:#000000;
        background:#42E64F;
        padding:5px;
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
        min-height:300px;
    }
    #blogcreditsleft, #blogcreditsright {
        color:#000000;
        padding:5px;
        width:250px;
        .gradientVBottomCenter();
    }
    #blogcreditsleft {
        float:left;
    }
    #blogcreditsright {
        float:right;
        text-align:right;
    }
```

Only way I can make it work is by setting the `position:absolute` and adding `left:65px` to push it into center of my "center" :)
But then my problem is that when more blog elements are added they won't just be under each other, because of the absolute position.

**I suspect** it's something about a missing `clear:both`, but I have no idea how to fix it though...

Can anyone help?

Edit: [image: border...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to stare at your site for almost a full minute to understand what you were talking about, and I suspect others are doing the same. That border is quite subtle (easy to miss).

The easiest way to fix it is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#blog` to ["clear the float"](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

*(Or `overflow: auto`, but past experience has taught me more upvotes go to `hidden`)*

Comment: This one did the trick. Thanks! I guess I have to save that link for further reading ;)

Comment: You probably want to change `#blog` to be a class, as in `<div class="blogpost">`, because surely you're going to have more than one blog post? ^^ (you can only have one instance of each `id`) (do the same for all the divs inside: `bloghead`, `blogbody`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) I'll change it to a class... and see how it goes when the SQL implementation is done :P

Answer (score 1):

Your floating elements are escaping the container div.

Add one more block level element to the markup after the "blogcreditsright".

```
<div class='clear'></div>
```

css

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```